# Exchange 2003 Setup - Items To Check

Tags: exchange-2003

I have setup up a domain name (the MX and A records are correctly pointing to my external IP) and a Windows 2003 Server Enterprise with Exchange 2003 Server (please no comments on the old version...).

I have installed Exchange Server 2003 and think that I have set things up correctly, but I cannot get any external emails in. I can send out to external mail however.

Can someone please give me a short checklist of things to check to get the inbound mail working.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check these three things first:

Have you added the appropriate domain(s) to your Recipient Policy and made Exchange authoratative for those domains? Have you enabled SMTP through your firewall to the Exchange server? Do you have a NAT rule in your firewall that NAT's the correct external ip address to the correct internal ip address?

Then try sending an email from an external client to an email address that you think should go to your Exchange server and see if you get an NDR. Then try to establish a connection to port 25 of the external ip address of the Exchange server and send a test message and see what response you get from the Exchange server. These two tests should give you some clue as to where the problem is.

Comment: Yep, have checked all of those and they are correct.

Comment: How about the test I suggested? Did you try those? If so, what were the results?